# JS library for interactive demo?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript library for my project :
I want to create an interactive demo
example : the user need to click in one place in particular then he goes to the next step of the demo

any help is welcome :)

Comment: This is not a question. Anyway this would be helpful to you http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to easily manipulate and listen to the user events and change CSS properties, add classes, animate, etc — as you can see in [**this demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/CKZgU/7/). But note that you still can use pure javascript to do the job.

**Here's the code I used to send the user to other part of the page, in the fiddle:**

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(".graph1").offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2)
    });
});
```